# Module socket not found lua

Tags: nginx, lua, redis

I am trying to use lua to access redis values from nginx. When i execute lua files on command line there everything is ok i am able to read and write values to redis. But i when try to execute the same files from nginx by accessing a location in which access_by_lua directive is written the following error logged in error log file

```
no field package.preload['socket'] 
no file '/home/sivag/redis/redis-lua/src/socket.lua'
no file 'src/socket.lua'
no file '/home/sivag/lua/socket.lua'
no file '/opt/openresty/lualib/socket.so'
no file './socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
no file '/opt/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

What is the reason for this and how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because your code executes the command `require("socket")`
This command will search for a file with that name in several directories. If successful the content will be executed as Lua code. If it is not successful you'll end up with your error message.

In order to fix this you have to add the path containing the file either to the system variable **LUA_PATH** or you have to add it to the global table `package.path` befor you require the file.
Lua will replace ? with the name you give to require()

For example

```
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. thisPathContainsTheLuaFile .. "?.lua"
```

Please read:

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require

https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

Comment: After digging into it  i resolved this issue in same way. However Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I just needed to install the `lua-socket` package, as the socket library is not built into the default Lua installation like it is in some other languages.