# Got error loading module while running a simple lua script as tcp client

Tags: lua

Run the following simple lua script but got error. I am running lua 5.2 on ubuntu.

```
local host, port = "127.0.0.1", 80
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())

tcp:connect(host, port);
--note the newline below
tcp:send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n");
```

Here is the error:

```
~/learn/lua$ lua te.lua
lua: te.lua:2: module 'socket' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/socket/init.lua'
    no file './socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './socket.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    te.lua:2: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module socket not found lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975868/module-socket-not-found-lua)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I googled and find the lua package manager that solved me problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after installing the package manager [luarocks](https://luarocks.org/) and then socket package.

Here are the commands from the page

```
$ wget https://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-2.4.1.tar.gz
$ tar zxpf luarocks-2.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd luarocks-2.4.1
$ ./configure; sudo make bootstrap
$ sudo luarocks install luasocket
$ lua
Lua 5.3.3 Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "socket"
```